# Using GitHub Api Code Search - Sort by recently indexed

Tags: github, github-api

I am searching for a specific code in GitHub using their API code search.

```
https://api.github.com/search/code?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}
```

I have for example the following:

```
https://api.github.com/search/code?q={"Hello World"}
```

I want to sort the search result by Recently Indexed, I am not sure what to put in the sort parameter. I checked GitHub documentation but I didn't find how.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Search code](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-code) section of the GitHub REST API Reference. By default, the search results of this endpoint are *best match*. The only option for the `sort` parameter is `indexed` and actually what you want. The following query is an example:

```
https://api.github.com/search/code?q=org:github+octocat&sort=indexed
```

Comment: is there any restriction from api when we sort by `indexed`, if I use sort by indexed i get 4 results instead of 30 (Note: no other parameter is changed)

Comment: @MudasirYounas I couldn't find any documentation about this. You could ask GitHub Support what is going on and whether they can explain the results you're getting. It would be interesting to know.

Comment: I myself have found no documentation about this issue, each time I refresh the api request I get different result, even though I have defined proper parameters. e.g. I get following different result for the same query for `per_page=100` : `10, 24, 47, 24, 24, 100, 48`

Comment: @MudasirYounas You can file a bug report with GitHub and see what they have to say: https://support.github.com/contact/bug-report

Comment: @MudasirYounas Github limits how long a search query can take. See: https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/troubleshooting-search-queries#potential-timeouts

So I guess it could be that adding the sort=indexed is making the query take longer

I have had greater success with a lower per_page value e.g. the default of 30

Comment: @pypmannetjies i think this is the reason API returns different result on each request, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2023, GitHub forces all the code search to be sorted based on "best match". [Reference here](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-03-10-changes-to-the-code-search-api/)